# Meaning of "Retourenstelle" and "weiterleiten"?

Tags: meaning

> Die Sendung wurde im HUB sortiert und an die Retourenstelle des Versenders weitergeleitet.

I would like to know what do "Retourenstelle" and "weiterleiten" mean?

Does this sentence mean my package is been returned to the sender?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does.
*Retourenstelle* is something like *return point* or *return address* (of the sender). And *weiterleiten* means *redirect* or *transfer*.

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean it has been sent back to the sender or it will be?

Comment: @Ginger It means, it has left HUB. If it arrived at `Retourenstelle` or not, it doesn't say.

Comment: @Toscho: Doesn't "it has been sent" say exactly that? The other would be "it has been received".

Comment: @celtschk I regard it as unclear, whether `has been sent` means or connotes a succesful delivery.

Answer (score 4):

> Die Sendung wurde im HUB sortiert und an die Retourenstelle des
>   Versenders weitergeleitet.

Translated:

> The delivery was sorted in the hub and was forwarded to the senders place / address for returning deliveries aka. return point .

Google Translated just for fun:

> The show was ranked in the HUB and forwarded to the return point of the shipper.

Answer (score 3):

By info from the German parcel service Hermes, who uses this phrase in tracking of its Packages, *Retourenstelle* has nothing to do with returning. It is some sort of “terminus technicus” of transship point.